# AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading

I have created a new class called Get_WebPage1 and init I have extends that class to use AsyncTask... as show below but still I get the same error:

```
public class Get_Webpage1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public String parsing_url = "";

    public Get_Webpage1(String url_2_get){      
        parsing_url = url_2_get;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(parsing_url);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        ....
                ....

        return html;
    }
}
```

Calling the class:

```
//Looper.myLooper().prepare(); 
         String url = "http://ofertaweb.ro/android/sleepandlovemusic/list_files.php";
         Get_Webpage1 obj = new Get_Webpage1(url);
         directory_listings = obj.doInBackground("test");//get_webpage_source();            songs_array = directory_listings.split(":::");
```

**end update**

I am trying to read the .htm file through website and it was working without any issues but suddenly I started getting this error message: and spend time googling but no avail..

`AndroidRuntime(5715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);       

        selelctedFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        prevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev);
        nextButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);


        player = new MediaPlayer();

        playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        prevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);

        viewOrders = new Runnable(){            
            public void run() {
                loadList();
                getOrders();
            }
        };

        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
        thread.start();
        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
    }
```

//here is what I am going to internet and reading the .htm page:

```
private void loadList(){

try 
  { 
     //Looper.myLooper().prepare(); 
     String url = "http://ofertaweb.ro/android/sleepandlovemusic/list_files.php";
     Get_Webpage obj = new Get_Webpage(url);
     directory_listings = obj.get_webpage_source(); //
     songs_array = directory_listings.split(":::");

   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(
    this, "You have to be connected to the internet for this application to work" +   e.getMessage(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   finish();
  } 
}
```

error stack:

```
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715): FATAL EXCEPTION: MagentoBackground
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView.loadList(SoftwarePassionView.java:262)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView.access$11(SoftwarePassionView.java:239)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView$4.run(SoftwarePassionView.java:87)
02-24 00:02:25.507: E/AndroidRuntime(5715):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715): Activity com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40526408 that was originally added here
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40526408 that was originally added here
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at com.softberries.sf.SoftwarePassionView.onCreate(SoftwarePassionView.java:94)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-24 00:02:26.517: E/WindowManager(5715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use AsyncTask for this. Do the loadList in `doInBackground`  and upload UI in `onPostExecute`.
This problem usually because you do something with UI in the thread. E.g Displaying a Toast

[Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: can you redirect me to webpage that do exactly what you trying to suggest me?

Comment: As far as I understand you question, you are trying to download a webpage, and display a progress dialog on the UI. So, in the `doInBackground`, you just put those heavy task. `onPreExecute`, you display a progressdialog and `onPostExecute` just `dismiss` it :)

Comment: Ah, Please run `Get_Webpage obj = new Get_Webpage(url); obj.execute()`. You may need to read the document fully

Comment: Hum... It looks ok, I'm not sure if there is somewhere update UI in the background. Could you please check the exception line to see where cause it throw the exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8157/discussion-between-cuong-thai-and-abu-hamzah)

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(
    this, "You have to be connected to the internet for this application to work" +   e.getMessage(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast can be shown only in UI Thread not in threads you create.. Right now you are doing the same...

And adding to that use AsyncTask, which is better for background process..

Comment: @AbuHamzah.. i can answer it but there already 100s of them.. google how to use AsyncTask.. you will get lot many...